# Не могу попасть в админку сайта WordPress

Tags: wordpress

столкнулся с проблемой (Страница недоступна Сайт www.site.com пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500) при попытке войти в админку.
Проблема не изза плагинов и тем, в журнале хостинга выдает ошибку (POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0)
Сам сайт работает
И если я ввожу и правильные и неправильные данные для входа админку, все равно выдает ошибку (Страница недоступна Сайт www.site.com пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500)

Comment: Какие плагины установили?

Comment: никаких плагинов не устанавливал, я пробовал отключать все плагины по одному, все равно не заработало

Comment: Какие либо изменения в код вносили? 500 ошибка может выскакивать из-за не корректного `php` скрипта (в большинстве случаев)

Comment: нет, разве что картинки время от времени меняю

Comment: Переименуйте папку `plugins` в папку `plugins1`. У вас должны отключиться все плагины. И вы попадёте в админку.  Потом по очереди их запускайте.

Comment: я так и пробовал, не работает

Comment: Даже с отключенными плагинами не заходит?

Comment: да пробовал поставить в config.php 
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
экран становится белым

Comment: Смените тему на стандартную, проверьте. Сайт переносили с одного адреса на другой? )

Comment: увы и это пробовал, не заработало.
сайт не переносили

Comment: Установите заново `WP` и подключите её к старой `БД`. Докидывая плагины.

Comment: пока переписывался с вами решил проблему,

Comment: вдруг кому нибудь понадобится.
просто удалил папку wp-admin и wp includes, загрузил новые, и заработало

Comment: Это значит, что либо вы испортили какой-то файл или файлы ранее в ядре WP, либо у вас вирус